# Python Pygame not showing image

Tags: python, pygame

I have problem, image "floor.png" is not showing on screen, blue color is showing. I was searching my old codes and I do everything same as in old working game.
But still image is invisible.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width = 600
display_height = 900

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_height, display_width))
pygame.display.set_caption("Parkour")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

lightblue = (102, 255, 255)

floorImg = pygame.image.load("floor.png")
floorX = 300
floorY = 300

crashed = False

def DrawPictures(floorX, floorY):
    gameDisplay.blit(floorImg, (floorX, floorY))


while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        DrawPictures(floorX, floorY)
        gameDisplay.fill(lightblue)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You blit the image on the screen surface correctly, but you just fill the screen afterwards. Just switch

```
DrawPictures(floorX, floorY)
gameDisplay.fill(lightblue)
```

to

```
gameDisplay.fill(lightblue)
DrawPictures(floorX, floorY)
```

Answer (score 0):

FIX:

Problem is in the image not in code, I tried another image and the image worked ...